# Counting true/false occurences on XML

Tags: java, xml, talend

I need to count specifics occurences on XML ("true" or "false") and get the results in a table

I try using a tXMLMap but so far without success.

Any idea where I can lookinf for?

My XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
    <customer id="1">
        <customerStatus vip="false" gold="false"/>
    </customer>
    <customer id="2">
        <customerStatus vip="true" gold="false"/>
    </customer>
    <customer id="3">
        <customerStatus vip="true" gold="true"/>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Wishes result:

| vip | gold |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I succeed with:
tFileInputXml -> tXMLMap -> tAggregateRow -> tLogRow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).